# How do I find the image (pixel?) value of the bottom right corner of an image with Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

At the upper left hand side of the image the "pixel" value is always going to be (0,0). But depending on the resolution of the camera and varying images the size of the picture changes, so how do I find the maximum pixel length and width of an image using python? (opencv or numpy)

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked, I realise, however, Pillow will do this for you.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Bill\Pictures\Tilly.jpg")
>>> im.size
(2448, 2448)
```

Answer (score 0):

The module that you used to read the image should usually give you a way to retrieve the dimension. I noticed you have the opencv tag. If you are using open cv , you can do this:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
#shape will give you [height, width, channel]
h, w = img.shape[0:2]
#get the bottom right pixel
bottom_right = img[h-1, w-1]
```